# EF DTO flat view model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I wonder whether there is a shortcut to make a flat view model from entity framework. The user table has a list of addresses. When I populate the view model I use FirstOrDefault for both streetline1 and streetline2. Is there a shortcut to populate the two strings from a list?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //EF Data
    User EFUser = new User();
    EFUser.UserId = 1;
    EFUser.Username = "Data";
    List<Address> ListOfAddress = new List<Address>();
    ListOfAddress.Add(new Address() { UserId=1, StreetLine1="address 1",StreetLine2="address line2 1" });
    EFUser.Address = ListOfAddress;

    ViewModelUserFlat vm = new ViewModelUserFlat();
    vm.UserId = EFUser.UserId;
    vm.UserName = EFUser.Username;
    vm.StreetLine1 = ListOfAddress.Select(a => a.StreetLine1).FirstOrDefault();
    vm.StreetLine2 = ListOfAddress.Select(a => a.StreetLine2).FirstOrDefault();
}
class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string StreetLine1 { get; set; }
    public string StreetLine2{ get; set; }
}
class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }
}
class ViewModelUserFlat
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string StreetLine1 { get; set; }
    public string StreetLine2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use AutoMapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to assign `StreetLine1` and `StreetLine2`. As yours `Address` is a list type you need to use `FirstOrDefault` or the index

```
var address = ListOfAddress.FirstOrDefault();
vm.StreetLine1 = address?.StreetLine1;
vm.StreetLine2 = address?.StreetLine2;
```

---

```
vm.StreetLine1 = address.FirstOrDefault().StreetLine1;
vm.StreetLine2 = address.FirstOrDefault().StreetLine2;
```

---

```
vm.StreetLine1 = ListOfAddress[0].StreetLine1;
vm.StreetLine2 = ListOfAddress[0].StreetLine2;
```